# Прочитать цифру в элементе span

Tags: java, jsoup, парсер

никак не пойму, никак не найду, как прочитать цифру в строке такого типа?

```html
<span class="price">6 600 <span class="rub" title="руб.">₽</span>/шт</span>
```

Элемент выделил `Element Prs=doc.getElementById("price")`;

А вот как из него число вытащить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Element Prs = doc.getElementById("price");
String prs = Prs.text();
```

Comment: После выполнения присваивания String res=Prs.text(); вылазит ошибка
    texte : Layta
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
     at parser1.main(parser1.java:53)

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно получить `6 600 ₽/шт`:

```
String price = Prs.text();
```

Если нужно получить только число `6600` (в общем случае оно может быть и не целое):

```
float price = Float.parseFloat(Prs.text().substring(0, Prs.text().lastIndexOf(" ")).replaceAll(" ", ""));
```

**UPD**.

Только стоимость (`6600.0`):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.layta.ru/rvi-ipc31ms-ir.html").get();
Element priceElement = doc.select("span.price").get(0);
float price = Float.parseFloat(priceElement.text().substring(0, priceElement.text().lastIndexOf(" ")).replaceAll(" ", ""));
```

Стоимость, валюта и единицы (`6 600 ₽/шт`):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.layta.ru/rvi-ipc31ms-ir.html").get();
Element priceElement = doc.select("span.price").get(0);
String price = priceElement.text();
```

Comment: Да я им и пользуюсь! Как именно из элемента вытащить цыфру?

Comment: @Михаил, Вам нужна только цифра или цифра и валюта?

Comment: мне нужна только цыфра, валюту я беру ,как я понимаю, через другой клас, rub.

Comment: @Михаил, Обновил ответ.

Comment: @Михаил, Попробуйте более точно сформулировать вопрос и поместить его в Ваше стартовое сообщение (его можно редактировать).

Comment: @Михаил, Дайте ссылку на саму страницу.

Comment: вот ссылка https://www.layta.ru/rvi-ipc31ms-ir.html

Comment: @Михаил, Смотрите **UPD**.